# Check first n checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a little problem here and can't find a solution, hope you guys will give me a right direction :)

So let's say there is a page with lot's checkboxes which are all in some td's of one big table.They don't have any classes.

What I want to do is to get first n checkboxes checked with javascript..
I'm coding a little chrome extension and need this for it :)

Any advice would be highly appreciated,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) with [:checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) to get the selected checkboxes and use [eq(index)](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to get particular checkbox

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/39Qtw/)**

```
$(':checkbox:checked:eq(0)')
```

To get first n checkbox you can use [:lt()](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/39Qtw/1/)**

```
n = 2;
$('checkbox:checked:lt(' + n +')')
```

Comment: I think OP need to use `$('checkbox:checked:lt(5)')`

Comment: Since it is the first n checkboxes I guess it should be `$('checkbox:checked:lt(' + n + ')')`